# Two tables with same columns or one table with additional column?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Say I have two tables (Apples and Oranges) with the same columns and just a different table name. Would there be any advantages/disadvantages to turning this into one table (lets say its called Fruit) with an additional column 'type' which would then either store a value of Apple or Orange?

Edit to clarify:

CREATE TABLE apples
(
id int,
weight int,
variety varchar(255)
)

CREATE TABLE oranges
(
id int,
weight int,
variety varchar(255)
)

OR

CREATE TABLE fruit
(
id int,
weight int,
variety varchar(255),
type ENUM('apple', 'orange')
)

Comment: What do you mean exactly. Can you ask this question with a database example ?

Comment: @CihanKüsmez added an example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on constraints:

- Do you have foreign keys or CHECKs on `apples` that don't exist on `oranges` (or vice-versa)?
- Do you need to keep keys unique across both tables (so no `apple` can have the same ID as some `orange`)?

If the answers on these two questions are: **"yes"** and **"no"**, keep the tables separate (so constraints can be made table-specific<sup>1</sup>).

If the answers are: **"no"** and **"yes"**, merge them together (so you can crate a key that spans both).

If the answers are: **"yes"** and **"yes"**, consider emulating inheritance<sup>2</sup>:

[image]

---

*<sup>1</sup> [Lookup data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12124811/533120) is a typical example of tables that look similar, yet must be kept separate so FKs can be kept separate.*

*<sup>2</sup> Specifically, this is the "all classes in separate tables" strategy for representing inheritance (aka. category, subclassing, subtyping, generalization hierarchy etc.). You might want to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037398/533120) for more info.*

Answer (score 2):

If there really is not any further business rules (and resultant underlying data requirements) that separate the two sub-types then I would use one table with an fk to a FruitType lookup table.

You dont mention what you will be using to access the schema which may affect which approach you take (e.g. if you are using a platform which provides an ORM to your database then this may be worth noting).

Comment: Yes, I will most likely be using an ORM, which I guess tips it in favour of two different tables?

Answer (score 2):

The advantage would be normalization. Your tables would then be in 2NF ([second normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form)). 
Your fruit `type` would be a foreign key to a table with those fruits like so:

```
CREATE TABLE fruit_type (type varchar(15))

CREATE TABLE fruits (id int, weight int, variety varchar(255), type varchar(15))
```